# Insert Query Does not work in php, does not throw any error either

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Trying to Insert users into my user table in php. Insert query doesn't seem to run. I tried to manually add email id, it checks for duplicate email id and does throw error stating email id exists, but for some reason it does not insert into data base. Any Suggestions ?`

```
<?php
$error = "";
if(array_key_exists("submit",$_POST )){


    $link = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root","","secretdi");

    if (mysqli_connect_error()){
        die ("Connection to Database failed!");
    }

    print_r($_POST);

    if (!$_POST ['email']){
         $error .= "Email Address is required<br>";
    }
    if (!$_POST ['password']){
         $error .= "Password is required<br>";
    }
    if ($error != ""){
        $error = "<p>There were Error(s) in your form <p>".$error;
    }else {
        $query = "SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email'])."' LIMIT 1 ";


        $result = mysqli_query ($link, $query );

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
           $error = "That Email Address is already taken. Try to Log In ";

        }else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`,`password`)VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["email"])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["password"])."')";

        }
            if (!mysqli_query($link, $query )){
                $error = "Could Not Sign You Up! Please Try Again Later. ";
            } else{
                echo "Sign-Up Successfull.";
            }
        }
    }


?>

<div id = "error" > <?php echo $error; ?> </div>
<form method="post">
    <input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder = " Your Email">
    <input type = "password" name = "password" >
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox">
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Sign - Up">
</form>`
```

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I am guessing your last if-else block should be inside the preceding else block.

Comment: @KshitijAnil are you using `id` field as **autoincrement** and **primary key** in your database

Comment: if (!mysqli_query($link, $query )){
                $error = "Could Not Sign You Up! Please Try Again Later. " . mysqli_error($link);
            } else {
                echo "Sign-Up Successfull.";
            }

I added error check code and it returned with " Field 'secretdi' doesn't have a default value"

what does this mean ?

Comment: `users` evidently has a NOT NULL field without a default value called `secretdi` (if that is not a typo); you cannot omit such fields from INSERT statements.